# how to take a String argument within a function returned as a tuple

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tuples, nested-loops

Okay so what I wanted was trying to do was cycle through the string arguments and then try add it into the tuple however I am unable to do that and I'm currently using the `print(tuple())` method.
I want to use return rather than print too.

Any help is much appreciated, I am a beginner in this too !

[currently what results I get, doubled words and of course because I used a for 
loop it adds each letter separately, so far this is the closest I've gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA38f.png)

```
def part1 (payroll, dept, salary, firstname, lastname):
    tuple1 = ()


    for i in payroll:
        payroll = payroll + i
    for i in dept:
        dept = dept + i
    for i in salary:
        salary = salary + i
    for i in firstname:
        firstname = firstname + i
    for i in lastname:
        lastname = lastname + i

    print(tuple(payroll))
    print(tuple(dept))
    print(tuple(salary))
    print(tuple(firstname))
    print(tuple(lastname))

part1('13214', 'CSEE', '27000', 'joey bob', 'Smith')
```

my desired output would be

```
(13214 CSEE 27000 joey bob Smith)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and desired output?

Comment: yeah I just edited it and add some more details as well as a pic of what the results were

Answer (score 1):

```
def part1(partonelist):
    return tuple(partonelist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    part1_list = ['13214', 'CSEE', '27000', 'joey bob', 'Smith']
    my_tup = part1(part1_list)
    print(my_tup)
```

It's a little cleaner to put them in a list... then simply call the tuple function.

This will print:
    ('13214', 'CSEE', '27000', 'joey bob', 'Smith')

Comment: I said the same thing hah. It seemed like he wanted a client to call a function though

Comment: where you wrote the if statement would that be counted as the main body of the program ?